# Why is pyparsing not a recursive descent parser?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

The wikipedia entry for [recursive descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) judges that pyparsing is not recursive descent. The definition of recursive descent identifies these properties:

1. Every nonterminal has a one-to-one mapping to a function that handles the expansion of the production rule for that nonterminal.
2. Tokens are read left to right (top down parsing)
3. Internally in these functions, it will call other functions to parse sub-expressions & these functions can be right recursive.

I understand that pyparsing uses a more object-oriented design rather than the parser combinator approach. Is this the technicality that disqualifies pyparsing ?

Comment: Just because pyparsing makes its function calls through object methods makes them no less a recursive function call. The one thing that might more likely disqualify pyparsing would be that to do repetition, pyparsing uses classes like OneOrMore that use iteration instead of recursion.  So `"A+B+C"` parses as `['A','+','B','+','C']` instead of `[['A','+','B'],'+','C']`

Comment: Also, there was an *extensive* discussion thread on comp.lang.python about 4 or 5 years ago.